# How to define scoped css classes in svelte, which depends on global attributes?

Tags: css, svelte

In my app, I have a global attribute `data-theme` which is defined on the `html` element:

```
<html data-theme="dark">
```

When styling my component, I want to define different colors, based on the theme:

```
<style lang="less">
  :global(html[data-theme='light']) {
    .title {
      color: black;
    }
  }
  :global(html[data-theme='dark']) {
    .title {
      color: white;
    }
  }
</style>
```

The problem is that `.title` is not scoped to my current component, but rather is being defined globally for any `.title` class.